# Enemy collision with pygame.sprite.spritecollide()

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

In my game, there is a sprite player which I can control. It can move right or left, it can jump, shoot fireballs(bullets) and a breathe fire. I have added an enemy which can move on itself from right to left on a limited distance that I set. What I would like to do now is make my player loose health if it collides with the enemy sprite using `pygame.sprite.spritecollide()`. However it isn't working out well I don't know how to fix my issue which is the following: if I run my code below it says `NameError: name 'enemy_list' is not defined`. The errored line is in Sprite1.py in the Player class under the update function. How do I fix my code? I created my Enemy class and Level class with the following website: https://opensource.com/article/18/5/pygame-enemy. I'm open to all suggestions. Thanks beforehand! I separated my code into three files: main.py, settings.py and Sprite1.py. Here's main.py:

```
import pygame
import os
import sys
import time
from pygame import mixer
from Sprite1 import *
from settings import *

'''
Setup
'''
pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.mixer.music.load('.\\sounds\\Fairy.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)


all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player(all_sprites)

player.rect.x = 500
player.rect.y = 500


eloc = []
eloc = [400,500]
enemy_list = Level.bad( 1, eloc )

showStartScreen(surface)
x = 0
'''
Main loop
'''

main = True

while main == True:
    background = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images', 'Bg.png')).convert()
    surface.blit(background, (0, 0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
            main = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.control(-steps,0)

            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.control(steps,0)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.control(steps,0)

            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.control(-steps,0)

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if not(isJump):
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            isJump = True
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            player.rect.y -= (jumpCount * abs(jumpCount)) * 1
            jumpCount -= 2
        else:
            jumpCount = 10
            isJump = False

    # dt = time since last tick in milliseconds.
    dt = clock.tick(60) / 1000
    all_sprites.update(dt)
    player.update(dt)
    all_sprites.draw(surface) #refresh player position
    enemy_list.draw(surface)
    for e in enemy_list:
        e.move()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Here's my settings.py:

```
import pygame
isJump = False
jumpCount = 10
width = 960
height = 720
fps = 40        # frame rate
pygame.display.set_caption('B.S.G.')
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
PLAYER_ACC = 0.5
PLAYER_FRICTION = -0.12
PLAYER_GRAV = 0.8
PLAYER_JUMP = 20
PLAYER_LAYER = 2
PLATFORM_LAYER = 1
RED = (255, 0, 0)

steps = 10      # how fast to move
```

And here's my Sprite1.py:

```
import pygame
import sys
import os
import time
from pygame import mixer
from pygame.locals import *
from settings import *
vec = pygame.math.Vector2

def showStartScreen(surface):
    show = True
    while (show == True):
        background = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images', 'Starting_scr.png'))
        # rect = surface.get_rect()
        surface.blit(background, (0,0))
        pygame.display.flip()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                show = False


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, all_sprites):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.movex = 0
        self.movey = 0
        self.frame = 0
        self.health = 10
        self.jumping = False
        self.images = []
        self.imagesleft = []
        self.imagesright = []
        self.direction = "right"
        self.alpha = (0,0,0)
        self.ani = 4 # animation cycles
        self.all_sprites = all_sprites
        self.add(self.all_sprites)
        self.fire_timer = .1
        self.bullet_timer = .1
        self.pos = vec(40, height - 100)
        self.vel = vec(0, 0)

        for i in range(1,5):
            img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images','hero' + str(i) + '.png')).convert()
            img.convert_alpha()
            img.set_colorkey(self.alpha)
            self.imagesright.append(img)
            self.image = self.imagesright[0]
            self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()


        for i in range(1,5):
            img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images','hero' + str(i) + '.png')).convert()
            img = pygame.transform.flip(img, True, False)
            img.convert_alpha()
            img.set_colorkey(self.alpha)
            self.imagesleft.append(img)
            self.image = self.imagesleft[0]
            self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()



    def control(self,x,y):
        '''
        control player movement
        '''
        self.movex += x
        self.movey -= y

    def update(self, dt):
        '''
        Update sprite position
        '''
        self.rect.x = self.rect.x + self.movex
        self.rect.y = self.rect.y + self.movey

        enemy_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, enemy_list, False)
        for enemy in ennemy_hit_list:
            self.health -= 1
            print(self.health)

        # moving left
        if self.movex < 0:
            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame > 3*self.ani:
                self.frame = 0
            self.image = self.imagesleft[self.frame//self.ani]
            self.direction = "left"

        # moving right
        if self.movex > 0:
            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame > 3*self.ani:
                self.frame = 0
            self.image = self.imagesright[self.frame//self.ani]
            self.direction = "right"

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            self.bullet_timer -= dt  # Subtract the time since the last tick.

        if keys[pygame.K_x]:
            self.fire_timer -= dt

        if self.bullet_timer <= 0:
            self.bullet_timer = 100  # Bullet ready.
            if keys:  # Left mouse button.
                # Create a new bullet instance and add it to the groups.
                if self.direction == "right":
                    Bullet([self.rect.x + self.image.get_width(), self.rect.y + self.image.get_height()/2], self.direction, self.all_sprites)
                else:
                    Bullet([self.rect.x, self.rect.y + self.image.get_height()/2], self.direction, self.all_sprites)
                self.bullet_timer = .5  # Reset the timer.

        if self.fire_timer <= 0:
            self.fire_timer = 100
            if keys:
                if self.direction == "right":
                    Fire([self.rect.x + 170, self.rect.y + self.image.get_height()/2], self.direction, self.all_sprites)
                else:
                    Fire([self.rect.x - 90, self.rect.y + self.image.get_height()/2], self.direction, self.all_sprites)
                self.fire_timer = .1

        if self.health == 0:
            self.kill()


class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    '''
    Spawn an enemy
    '''
    def __init__(self,x,y,img):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images',img))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.counter = 0 # counter variable

    def move(self):
        '''
        enemy movement
        '''
        distance = 20
        speed = 15

        if self.counter >= 0 and self.counter <= distance:
            self.rect.x += speed
        elif self.counter >= distance and self.counter <= distance*2:
            self.rect.x -= speed
        else:
            self.counter = 0

        self.counter += 1

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    IMAGE = None
    FLIPPED_IMAGE = None

    def __init__(self, pos, direction, *sprite_groups):
        super().__init__(*sprite_groups)

        # cache images
        if not Bullet.IMAGE:
            Bullet.IMAGE = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images','fireball.png'))
            Bullet.FLIPPED_IMAGE = pygame.transform.flip(Bullet.IMAGE, True, False)

        if direction == "right":
            self.vel = pygame.math.Vector2(750, 0)
            self.image = Bullet.IMAGE
        else:
            self.vel = pygame.math.Vector2(-750, 0)
            self.image = Bullet.FLIPPED_IMAGE

        self.pos = pygame.math.Vector2(pos)
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)

    def update(self, dt):
        # Add the velocity to the position vector to move the sprite
        self.pos += self.vel * dt
        self.rect.center = self.pos  # Update the rect pos.
        if not pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect().colliderect(self.rect):
            self.kill()

class Fire(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    IMAGE = None
    FLIPPED_IMAGE = None

    def __init__(self, pos, direction, *sprite_groups):
        super().__init__(*sprite_groups)

        # cache images
        if not Fire.IMAGE:
            Fire.IMAGE = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images','fire_drag.png'))
            Fire.FLIPPED_IMAGE = pygame.transform.flip(Fire.IMAGE, True, False)

        if direction == "right":
            self.image = Fire.IMAGE
            self.vel = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)
        else:
            self.image = Fire.FLIPPED_IMAGE
            self.vel = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)
        self.pos = pygame.math.Vector2(pos)
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)

    def update(self, dt):
        self.too = True
        self.pos += self.vel * dt

        self.rect.center = self.pos  # Update the rect pos.
        if self.too == True:
            self.kill()

class Level():
    def bad(lvl,eloc):
        if lvl == 1:
            enemy = Enemy(eloc[0],eloc[1],'cookie1.png') # spawn enemy
            enemy_list = pygame.sprite.Group() # create enemy group
            enemy_list.add(enemy)              # add enemy to group
        if lvl == 2:
            print("Level " + str(lvl) )
        return enemy_list

    def loot(lvl,lloc):
        print(lvl)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enemy_list` is defined in global namespace, in `main.py`, thus it is not accessible in the module `Sprite.py`.

Add an additional argument to the `update` method of the class `Player`:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def update(self, dt, enemy_list):
        # [...]

        enemy_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, enemy_list, False) 

        # [...]
```

Since `player` is a member of `all_sprites`, you have to add the argument to the `update` methods of the other sprites (`Enemy`, `Bullet`), too.

Pass `enemy_list` to the `update` method `all_sprites` in the main application loop. Note the update method of `Player` is invoked by `all_sprites.update`, thus `player.update(dt, enemy_list)` is superflous:

```py
while main == True:
    # [...]

    all_sprites.update(dt, enemy_list)

    # [...]
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I added the codes you suggested but it gave me this ''' TypeError: update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'enemy_list' ''' in sprite.py not Sprite1.py

Comment: @M3lon_sauc3 Do the same for the `update` methods of the other sprites (`Enemy`, `Bullet`), too. And do `all_sprites.update(dt, enemy_list)`. I've extended the answer.